# How can I create a Shopify contact form that will know which product page a user came from?

Tags: shopify

We created code to display "rental only" and a link to a rental/contact form when users land on a certain product. However, we need a way to pass in a hidden field that will tell us which product the user came from. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use browser cache to save the page/last visited page. Trigger the following code when someone click on the link to the contact form

```
localStorage.setItem('last_visited_page','<product_name/page_name>')
```

Then follow the instruction on this page - [Add Fields to the Liquid Contact Form](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/communicating-with-customers/provide-contact-points/adding-fields-to-the-liquid-contact-form)

One a new field is added, hide it using css: `display:none` and give an `id="something"` to it.

On page load use JS to fill that field from the browser cache:

```
$(document).on("ready",function(){
  var last_page = localStorage.getItem('last_visited_page')
  $('#something').val(last_page)
}
```

If they directly contact you without visiting a required page it'll blank. Since localStorage is a permanent cookie, it'll stay there even if the user closes the brower (unless he clears local cache and cookies.

More details on usage of [local storage/browser](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try that